# Efficient algorithm for maximum sum contiguous subarray implemented in ruby times out

Tags: python, arrays, ruby, algorithm

I solved the maximum sum contiguous subarray problem on Interviewbit in Ruby. The problem is as follows:

```
Find the contiguous subarray within an array (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum.

For example:

Given the array [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],

the contiguous subarray [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.

For this problem, return the maximum sum.
```

The algorithm i used is i think one of the most efficient ones to solve this problem. However i get a 'Time Limit Exceeded' . Surprisingly the same algorithm implemented in Python gets accepted !.  Below are the ruby and python versions of the algorithm. What could be the problem with the ruby implementation ? . Please help. Thanks.

**Ruby**

```
 def maxSubArray(a)
            max_so_far = a[0]
            curr_max = a[0]
            arr_size = a.size

            for i in 1...arr_size
                curr_max = (a[i] > curr_max+a[i]) ? a[i] : curr_max+a[i]
                max_so_far = (max_so_far > curr_max) ? max_so_far : curr_max 
            end

            max_so_far

    end
```

**Python**

```
def maxSubArray(self, A):
        max_ending_here = max_so_far = A[0]
        for x in A[1:]:
            max_ending_here = max(x, max_ending_here+x)
            max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
        return max_so_far
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python code loops through the elements of the array directly; the Ruby code access those elements by index, three times. Changing the Ruby code to do the same as Python results in about 70% faster code.

```
def maxSubArray2(ar)
  curr_max = max_so_far = ar[0]
  for x in ar
    curr_max = (x > curr_max+x) ? x : curr_max + x
    max_so_far = curr_max if curr_max > max_so_far
  end
  max_so_far
end
```

Comment: Even with the above approach i still get time limit exceeded with ruby !. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/392ab5dd56b2c637f12cac8c58d92079 . Should i conclude that ruby is not good enough for implementing algorithms ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `each_cons` wrapped in an iterator for the Ruby implementation, like so:

```
def maxSubArray(arr)
  new_arr = []
  return 0 if arr.empty?

  arr.each_with_index do |_, idx|
    arr.each_cons(idx + 1) do |subarr|
      new_arr << subarr.sum
    end
  end
  new_arr.max < 0 ? 0 : new_arr.max
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is probably [just objectively slower at some tasks](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/ruby.html). You might want to try another kind of for loop, namely [Integer#times](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Integer.html), but it might be that it's just too slow alltogether.